# Can a tagged but only-allowed friend's friends see the status where he is tagged?

Tags: facebook, privacy, friends, status

If I
(1) post a Facebook status;
(2) tag one friend in the status;
(3) and customise the privacy settings of the status so that only this one friend is allowed to see it,
will this friend's friends see my status as a post on this friend's timeline because I have tagged this friend?